# Passing parameter from one batch file to another not working

Tags: linux, batch-file, putty, winscp, sshpass

I want to login to a Linux environment say ENV1 and run a command from ENV1, to copy a file from ENV1 to ENV2 automatically.

Everything is working fine when i am using below commands.

I am running "BATCH_FILE.bat" which reads command from "COMMANDS_TO_RUN_IN_LINUX.bat" file, to copy file from ENV1 to ENV2.

BATCH_FILE.bat file content as below:

```
"C:\putty.exe" -ssh myuser_ENV_ONE@ENV1_ipaddress -pw "mypassword_ENV_ONE" -m "C:\COMMANDS_TO_RUN_IN_LINUX.bat"
```

COMMANDS_TO_RUN_IN_LINUX.bat content as below:

```
sshpass -p "mypassword_ENV_TWO" scp /u01/file.txt myuser_ENV_TWO@ENV2_ipaddress:/u01/file.txt
```

Now comes the issue, I want user to pass both the environment ipaddress(ENV1 and ENV2) rather then hard coding and for that I modified the command as below:

Modified BATCH_FILE.bat file content as below:

```
"C:\putty.exe" -ssh myuser_ENV_ONE@%1 -pw "mypassword_ENV_ONE" -m "C:\COMMANDS_TO_RUN_IN_LINUX.bat"
```

COMMANDS_TO_RUN_IN_LINUX.bat content as below:

```
sshpass -p "mypassword_ENV_TWO" scp /u01/file.txt myuser_ENV_TWO@%2:/u01/file.txt
```

I'm passing ENV1 detail while running the BATCH_FILE.bat from command line and its working fine and is getting logged in ENV1.

But I have no idea now to pass the ENV2 as well which in turn will replace %2.

I tried using %1 instead just to check if the parameter %1 is getting passed from BATCH_FILE.bat to COMMANDS_TO_RUN_IN_LINUX.bat and in turn it will copy file from  ENV1 back to ENV1.

But that also gave me an error "unknown host %1" .i.e. it wasn't passed as parameter.

I have gone through some posts but none of them has resolved my issue.

Comment: Also note that you should probably use Plink, (from PuTTY package), instead of PuTTY itself. See [Automating command/script execution using PuTTY](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39361444/850848).

Comment: Thanks Martin, I have gone through the above link and i agree on how -m works but the workaround mentioned didn't work for me...

Comment: I'll try with plink as well and will update

Comment: Tried Plink and "C:\plink.exe" -ssh myuser@%1 -pw "mypass123" "/u01/./COPY_SCRIPT.sh %1" this is working i.e. i am able to transfer the file from same environment (used %1 in both places and passed 1 parameter)

Comment: But when i am trying to pass 2 parameter as "C:\plink.exe" -ssh myuser@%1 -pw "mypass123" "/u01/./COPY_SCRIPT.sh %2" its not working

Comment: and  i am getting below error

Comment: "C:\plink.exe" -ssh oracle@11.111.11.11 -pw "pass123" "/u01/./COPY_SCRIPT.sh 11.111.11.12"
ssh: Could not resolve hostname : Name or service not known
lost connection

Comment: "C:\plink.exe" -ssh oracle@11.111.11.11 -pw "pass123" "/u01/./COPY_SCRIPT.sh 11.111.11.11" is working fine

Comment: So it looks like that 11.111.11.11 is not able to identify 11.111.11.12 ??

Comment: But the strange thing is if i run COPY_SCRIPT.sh manually from putty, copying from 11.111.11.11 to 11.111.11.12 is working fine even with parameters

Comment: OK, so now you have a different question. So either edit your current question accordingly. Or accept that this question is duplicate and post a new question for your new problem.

Comment: I have accepted it as duplicate, I'll post new question..Would be great if you can help me in that new question.