# how with putty run a command without any interactivity with the user?

Tags: ssh, putty

I am somewhat familiar with how putty in an interactive environment.  But my new backup platform does not allow me to do anything interactively.  I am told that the command is this
`putty.exe -ssh username@serveraddress ls` if I want to list directories for example. How with putty can I run a command in my mac with no user interaction?

Comment: See [Automating command/script execution using PuTTY](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39361444/850848).

Comment: use plink.exe - it is companion tool from the same suite